# Create Statement fails

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to load a jar at runtime, `ojdbc14.jar` in this case.
The jar gets loaded properly, and I am also able to create a connection to the DB(oracle).
But whenever I try to do a `connection.createStatement();` it gives me this Exception

> $Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried
>   to access method
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.(Loracle/jdbc/driver/DBConversion;)V
>   from class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.(OracleStatement.java:641)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.(T4CStatement.java:702)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocateStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:50)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:584)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:550)
>           at genInstaller.Controller.MetadataScriptManager.checkTableExistence(MetadataScriptManager.java:450)
>           ...   ...     ...

Edit:

```
String dbDriverLocn = //location of ojdbc14.jar 
String strDBDriverURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@frewper:1521:ORCL" 
String strDBUserName = "frewper" 
String strDBUserPassword = "frewper" 

new LoadClassTest().callToLoad(dbDriverLocn); 

try 
 { 
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(strDBDriverURL,strDBUserName,strDBUserPassword); 
  Statement st = conn.createStatement(); 
   //Exception occurs here 
 } catch (SQLException e) 
 { 
   e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

Comment: My guess! you are working with applet. Isn't it?

Comment: No actually its a swing application...

Comment: Does LoadClassTest load's the .jar file dynamically?

Comment: yes it does...it extends URLCLassLoader, and add the jar to the SystemClassLoader

Comment: So I think your Class.forName should be : `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",true,instance_of_LoadClassTest)`

Comment: did that, still the same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=850337) it seems that you have compiled against an older version of the jdbc driver and during run time you try to access methods of no longer visible classes, see Oracles [Announcement: oracle.jdbc.driver package desupport](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/ann.jspa?annID=201) .

Answer (score 0):

Try using other jar file for JDBC driver.